# Proof check: $(4n)!$ is divisible by $2^{3n}3^{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification

**Question:** Show that $(4n)!$ is a multiple of $2^{3n}3^{n}$ for all $n$.

**Proof:** It's easy (involves kinda messy calculation tho) to show by induction that $(4n)!$ is a multiple of $2^{3n}$. Now, since every third number in the sequence $1,2,...,4n$ is divisible by $3$, there are at least $\dfrac{4n}{3}>n$ many 3's. This proves that $(4n)!$ is also a multiple of $3^n$ and the claim follows.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Yes, it's correct and valid

Comment: It might be, but you didn't really show your induction for $2^{3n}\mid (4n)!$.  If anything, the $3^n$ part is the much easier part (and it would be very easy to prove by induction).  So I would question why you are uncertain about the $3^n$ part but don't seek verification for the messy induction?

Comment: At least $\left\lfloor\frac{4n}3\right\rfloor$. For example, when $n=1$, there are not at least $\frac{4n}{3}$ multiples of $3$ - that would mean at least $2$ multiples of $3$. FWIW, the number of powers of prime $p$ which divide into $m!$ can be written as: $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left\lfloor\frac{m}{p^k}\right\rfloor.$$

Comment: @ErickWong I don't know why induction didn't work for the $3$, probably some error in calculations I guess. I didn't show my induction because I'm sure of it and it's too messy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your proof is fine.

An alternative for the factors of $3$:  we show that one of $m,m+1,m+2$ is divisible by $3$ for any integer $m$, and then we can use that instead for your induction step for powers of $3$.

Basically, you need in your induction step to show that $(4n+1)(4n+2)(4n+3)(4n+4)$ is divisible by both $8=2^3$ and $3$. It is divisible by $8$ obviously - just factor it as:

$$8(4n+1)(2n+1)(4n+3)(n+1)$$

The fact that it is divisible by $3$ follows from my statement above - one of $4n+1,4n+2,4n+3$ is divisible by $3$.

Or you could argue that $$\binom{4n+4}{4}=\frac{(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}{4\cdot 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}$$ is always an integer, so the numerator is divisible by the denominator. (That is likely the combinatorial argument you referenced in comments - the value:

$$\frac{(4n)!}{24^n}$$

can be considered as a count of the number of ordered partitions of the set $\{1,2,\dots,4n\}$ into $n$ sets of size $4$.)

Comment: Oooh yes that's better. Thanks. There is also a very short and elegant combinatorial proof of this which uses counting arguments for multisets.

Answer (score 2):

It works. As an alternative, through a [well-known formula](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/blue/LegendresTheorem.shtml):
$$\nu_2((4n)!)=\sum_{m\geq 1}\left\lfloor\frac{4n}{2^m}\right\rfloor=\color{red}{3n}+\sum_{m\geq 3}\left\lfloor\frac{4n}{2^m}\right\rfloor\geq 4n-1-\log_2(n) $$
and:
$$\nu_3((4n)!)=\sum_{m\geq 1}\left\lfloor\frac{4n}{3^m}\right\rfloor\geq\color{red}{n}+\sum_{m\geq 2}\left\lfloor\frac{4n}{3^m}\right\rfloor\geq 2n-2-\log_3(n). $$

Comment: Of course, proving that value for $\nu_p(m!)$ requires induction...

Comment: Induction can hardly be avoided for a function that is defined only by a recursoin.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: it depends on the proof strategy. One may just notice that in $[1,n]$ there are $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ even numbers, $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{4}\right\rfloor$ multiples of four and so on, any of these elements contributing by one to $\nu_2(n!)$.

Comment: "Notice" is not proof. Prove those "notices" rigorously, you are going to use induction.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: as you wish, I am removing the "induction-free" part.

Comment: Anyway, the induction is in (the proof of) *Legendre's formula*, which is, as you said, well-known.

Comment: I think the second formula is slightly off--for $n = 2$, $\nu_3(4n!) = 2$ whereas $2n - 1 - \log_3(n) = 2.36\ldots$.

Comment: @6005: you're right, now fixed.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Cool. It doesn't matter too much what the constants are anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**Combinatorial Proof**

Let $N$ be the number of ways to select $n$ groups of four from $4n$ people.  Then, if we label the groups by numbers $1$, $2$, $\ldots$, $n$, we can do it in $n!\cdot N$ ways.  Alternatively, for $k=1,2,\ldots,n$, there are $4n-4(k-1)$ people from which four shall be chosen for the group with label $k$, and this can be done in $\binom{4n-4(k-1)}{4}$ ways.  Therefore,
$$n!\cdot N=\prod_{k=1}^n\,\binom{4n-4(k-1)}{4}=\frac{(4n)!}{(4!)^n}\,.$$
Consequently,
$$N=\frac{(4n)!}{(4!)^nn!}$$
is an integer.  Hence,
$$\frac{(4n)!}{(4!)^n}=\frac{(4n)!}{2^{3n}3^n}$$
is an integer, which is divisible by $n!$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the Legendre theorem:

For $n!=p_1^{\alpha_1} p_2^{\alpha_2} \cdots $   then
$$
\alpha_i=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \left[ \frac{n}{p_i^k}\right]
$$

Comment: What is Legendre theorem? How can we use it to prove this equation?

Comment: At the very least, *link* to the theorem. Quite likely, the goal is to prove by induction, so it's not likely that the OP has gotten to that point, yet. And this is trivial to prove without Legendre.

Comment: Wow I've never heard of that theorem. Cool.

Answer (score 0):

**First, show that this is true for $n=3$:**

$(4\cdot3)!=3\cdot11550\cdot(2^{3\cdot3}\cdot3^{3\cdot1})$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$(4n)!=3\cdot{k}\cdot(2^{3n}\cdot3^{n})$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$(4n+4)!=$

$\color\red{(4n)!}\cdot(4n+1)\cdot(4n+2)\cdot(4n+3)\cdot(4n+4)=$

$\color\red{3\cdot{k}\cdot(2^{3n}\cdot3^{n})}\cdot(4n+1)\cdot(4n+2)\cdot(4n+3)\cdot(4n+4)=$

$3\cdot{k}\cdot(2^{3n}\cdot3^{n})\cdot8\cdot(4n+3)\cdot(4n+1)\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(n+1)=$

$k\cdot(2^{3(n+1)}\cdot3^{n+1})\cdot(4n+3)\cdot(4n+1)\cdot(2n+1)\cdot(n+1)$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how you got the first factor of 3 in your induction hypothesis.

Comment: @user84413: I showed it for the first case ($n=3$), and assumed it for the general case ($n$). You'd still need to show it for $n=1$ and $n=2$, but that's just a simple numerical calculation.

Comment: Thanks for your reply; the thing I didn't understand is why you have a factor of 3k (instead of k) on the righthand side when you are assuming that it's true for n.

Comment: @user84413: Because I want to use this factor in order to "stick it" into the $3^n$ (and make it $3^{n+1}$) during the induction step. I have shown that I can use $3\cdot11550$ in the basic case, so I have allowed myself to use $3\cdot{k}$ in the general case.

Comment: If you do that, though, you're making the induction hypothesis that $(4n)!$ is divisible by $2^{3n}3^{n+1}$ (instead of $2^{3n}3^n$).  Of course, that is fine, if you can show that $(4(n+1))!$ is divisible by $2^{3(n+1)}3^{n+2}$.

Comment: @user84413: But I did not choose to make this induction hypothesis. I chose to make the induction hypothesis of $(4n)!=3\cdot{k}\cdot(2^{3n}\cdot3^{n})$. I could have just as well made the induction hypothesis of $(4n)!=11550\cdot{k}\cdot(2^{3n}\cdot3^{n})$, or even the induction hypothesis that you suggested. But neither one of those would have served my purpose. You can choose to make any induction hypothesis that you want, just as long as you first show that it applies for some basic case.

Comment: The induction hypothesis you use, though, has to correspond to the statement you are trying to prove true for every n.  In this case, you want to use that $(4n)!=k(2^{3n}3^{n})$ for some k; it's not valid to use an extra factor of 3. (I believe you can modify your argument, though, to prove that $(4n)!$ is divisible by $2^{3n}3^{n+1}$ for $n\ge3$.)

Comment: @user84413: Why not? I have shown that $(4\cdot3)!=3\cdot11550\cdot(2^{3\cdot3}\cdot3^{3\cdot1})$ for the basic case of $n=3$. Now I wish to assume that $(4\cdot3)!=3\cdot{k}\cdot(2^{3\cdot3}\cdot3^{3\cdot1})$ is true for $n$, and then use this assumption in order to prove it for $n+1$.

Comment: The induction hypothesis depends on the statement you are trying to prove for all n, and not on the base case; so your induction hypothesis is not correct if you are trying to prove the problem as it is stated.

Comment: @user84413: In case you haven't noticed, we are arguing whether I should put that $3$ as a factor or as an exponent ($3^{n+1}$). This i ridiculous!!!

Comment: No, that is not what we're disagreeing about at all.  The induction hypothesis has to correspond to the statement you're trying to prove, not something you get from the base case.